# Oh! It's another Abbreviated Riddle

Tags: riddle

I've been wanting to make another one of these :)

> My Prefix is an abbreviation of the whole word
>
> Which consists of just a few letters
>
> My Infix can be many things
>
> But it is also an abbreviation for 3 different words
>
> My Suffix is something that you may find on the streets (If you're lucky)
>
> But of course, you need to add a letter to it before that happens

To clarify :

> What I meant by the forth line (**Abbreviation of 3 different words**) is like, for example, **STR** for *Strength, String, Strung* --> *Just pretend that those are correct*. The abbreviations **has to be correct**, though, **for the riddle** :D

Hint :

> The word is something everyone will always gain

Comment: I find these abbreviation rileys a little bit more tricker than the usual ones :P

Comment: I know right. A word suddenly came across my mind and I made this new abbreviation riddle :D

Comment: 3-letter abbreviations in particular don't really narrow it much more than "it has 3 letters". If you take three random letters and look them up, the chances are very high that it's an existing TLA for one or several things.

Comment: No I meant that it can be an abbreviation of 3 things like for example (str for strength, stringth, strungth --> just pretend those are english words ). Btw, just edited my post, thanks for hinting that out :) @jafe

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah, no problem mate :) @jafe

Comment: What if you made a riley rebus puzzle? Like a rebus for the prefix, infix, and the suffix.@KevinL

Comment: Any prefix of any word (except the whole word) is an [abbreviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation) of that word, maybe not one which is commonly used (see Zimonze's answer for example).

Comment: Hmm, I know that but let's just say that the abbreviation should be quite common enough @JonathanAllan

Comment: @Duck Ooh, haven't thought of that. Maybe I'll come up with one in the near future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a long shot, but is it

> EXPERIENCE

My Prefix is an abbreviation of the whole word

Which consists of just a few letters

> EXP is an abbreviation for EXPERIENCE.

My Infix can be many things

> PER has many definitions, such as
>
>  The apples are $1 PER pound.
>
>  Send it PER express mail.
>
>  I made it PER your instructions.

But it is also an abbreviation for 3 different words

> PER is short for words such as PERCENTILE, PERIOD, and PERSON.

My Suffix is something that you may find on the streets (If you're lucky)

But of course, you need to add a letter to it before that happens

> ENCE, add P to make PENCE

Hint

> You gain experience by accomplishing tasks.

Comment: The infix part is incorrect but you got the answer :D

Comment: You also haven't answered the hint

Comment: Don't forget to also answer the third line. It has a different meaning from the forth line :)

Comment: OK all correct :)